# Is it possible to make a mobile UI editor

Tags: android, ios

I know how to generate HTML from json, but I don't know how to generate mobile App UI from json (not webview). Like existing drag and drop web page editor, I want to make a similar editor but render UI in mobile App without using webview. The user can input text and uploads images, set text and images' style (like the position and margin), when click some text or image it navigate to another page. All other users can see the page he or she made and interact with the page. The user can even drag and drop a textbox somewhere to allow other users to fill comments.

Is this possible in mobile App without webview? How to implement it (android & iOS)?

Comment: Certainly it's possible. Not much else to say other than "start working on it."

Comment: You basically just described Figma: figma.com